# PCM1789 DAC direct connection to TPA6138A2 headphone amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio, dac

Is it possible to directly connect PCM1789 DAC to TPA6138A2 headphone amplifier?

According to datasheet PCM1789 output are differential outputs and the input of TPA6138A2 is also differential inputs. The PCM1789 datasheet suggest putting LPF/Differential to single ended circuit. I wanted to know whether this LPF/Differential to single ended circuit can be avoided and make a direct connection.

It's my first time for all this so I needed some guidance.

pcm1789: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1789.pdf
tpa6138a2: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa6138a2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your design should follow this circuit in TPA6138 datasheet. If you notice carefully, this is in fact a differential to single ended circuit.

Comment: yes, but can you confirm that one can connect the output of the PCM1789 to the input of TPA6138 directly?

Comment: No you can't. The DAC reference voltage is 2.5V, a DC blocking cap must be use. If you want direct connection, choose another DAC that has dual supply.

Comment: do you think DC blocking cap of 0.1uF between the DAC and TPA6138 might work(to each inputs)? for example in the figure above, the C3 can be 0.1uF blocking the DC of the incoming audio signal?

Comment: That's not enough, you need to study low pass filter design for your audio application. Aim for 40kHz low pass filter with at least 10uF cap.

Comment: as mentioned in PCM1789 DAC datasheet, i had LPF/diff. to single circuit connected at its output but then output will be single ended(total 2 o/p) but the TPA6138 expects differential inputs(total 4 i/p)

Comment: There's no need for that. Just connect your DAC output to C3 in the diagram.

Comment: hi, do you mean like this?https://ibb.co/kT11ek

Comment: Yes. Your circuit looks good.

Comment: the circuit didn't work with electrolytic 0.1uF, 1uF and 10uF. are the signal levels compatible between the DAC and amplifier? as i read they ought to be.

Comment: sound is there but very noisy, tried different electrolytic cap even 22uF and 100uF. moreover, i put no cap at all and they are all the same, more or less with or without cap.

Comment: Using a scope to probe the ADC output, what did you see?